# Google Smart Home - TemperatureSetting Temperature Range not working

Tags: google-smart-home

I made a google Smart Home able to control a water heater pump with google smarthome touch control. What it need to control is desired temperature and mode (on off).

I was not able to make that work with the "heater" device so instead I use the "thermostat" device.

Everything work except one thing : the temperature range.

In my onSync request I enter a range between 60F° and 104F°, but it doesn't work on the device.

[My min is 50F°](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Et3Yt.png) and [My max is 90F°](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0b7yI.png)

Here my onSync request.

```
function onSync(firebaseRef) { return async (body, headers) => {

    return {
        requestId: body.requestId,
        payload: {
            agentUserId: uId,
            devices: [{
                id: pId,
                type: 'action.devices.types.THERMOSTAT',
                traits: [
                    'action.devices.traits.TemperatureSetting',
                ],
                name: {
                    defaultNames: ['My Heat Pump'],
                    name: 'Heat Pump',
                    nicknames: ['Pump'],
                },
                deviceInfo: {
                    manufacturer: 'test',
                    model: '1',
                    hwVersion: '1.0',
                    swVersion: '1.0.1',
                },
                willReportState: true,
                attributes: {

                    // TemperatureSetting
                    availableThermostatModes: 'off,heat',
                    thermostatTemperatureRange: {
                        minThresholdCelsius: 15.555,
                        maxThresholdCelsius: 40.0
                    },
                    thermostatTemperatureUnit: 'F'

                },
            }],
        },
    };
}
}
```

Do you know how to get the good temperature range ?

Bonus : It is possible to have a temperature touch control working with something else like a heater ?

Answer (score 0):

I had this answer from u/devunwired on Reddit:

> > In my onSync request I enter a range between 60F° and 104F°, but it
> >     doesn't work on the device.
>
> This is a known issue that the Google Home app does not currently render the temperature range provided (the value is respected in voice
>   queries). You can follow (and start) the feature request here:
>   [b/154169625](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154169625)

Permalink: https://www.reddit.com/r/GoogleAssistantDev/comments/guoyih/temperaturesetting_temperature_range/fskfx4f/